# jQuery, on hover show text snippet in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an interactive banner that when you hover over the banner, you can hover over each image and see a snippet of text.

Im trying to make this snippet of text appear in my div titled 'textbox' only im struggling to make it change when the mouse leaves each image (you will have to see my fiddle for an example)

Let each image load BEFORE hovering over the html blue box...

http://jsfiddle.net/uEDBA/3/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {

    var people = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Adam',
        bio: 'This is Adam\'s Biography. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem',
        image: 'justin.jpg'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Brian',
        bio: 'This is Brian\' Biography. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem',
        image: 'chris.jpg'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Charlie',
        bio: 'This is Charlie\'s Biography. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem',
        image: 'sam.jpg'
    },

    ];

    w = 750;
    h = 450;

    var counter = 0;

    (function nextFade() {
        counter++;
        var data = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
        var figure = $('<figure style="float:left; width:150px; height:150px; background:red;" />');
        var information = '<img src="http://www.placekitten.com/150/150" /><figcaption><h6>Meet ' + data.name + '</h6><p>' + data.bio + '</p><a href="#">Read about ' + data.name + '.</a> </figcaption>';
        figure.html(information).appendTo('.interactive-banner-faces').hide().fadeIn(100, function () {
            if (counter < 15) {
                nextFade();
            } else {

                $('.interactive-banner-faces').children(':nth-child(12n+1), :nth-child(12n+2), :nth-child(12n+3)').addClass('rightTxt');

                // On mouseover, fadeout the text overlay so we can play with the banner
                $('.interactive-banner').on('mouseenter', function () {

                    $('.textbox').html(data.bio).fadeIn();
                    $('.overlay').stop().animate({
                        'top': '-450px'
                    }, 200, 'easeInCirc');
                }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                    $('.textbox').html('').fadeOut();
                    $('.overlay').stop().animate({
                        'top': '0'
                    }, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
                });

            };
        });
    })();

});

});
```

Comment: do you still want to show the details in the gray box next to the images? or only inside the red box?

Comment: Only inside the red box @Andy

Comment: You could just position the gray figcaption absolutely in the top right with css. Or isn't that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/uEDBA/4/